# Identity in merge statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql script to populate data

Here is it

```
  PRINT 'Update rows in [Survey].[Portfolio]'
GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Survey].[Portfolio] ON
    MERGE [Survey].[Portfolio] AS t USING (
        VALUES
            (1),
            (2)
    ) AS s([Id]) ON (t.[Id] = s.[Id])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
    ([Id])
VALUES
    (s.[Id])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
    t.[Id] = s.[Id]

    -- delete rows that are in the target but not the source
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;

GO
    PRINT '' PRINT 'Operation applied [Survey].[Portfolio]' PRINT ''
GO
```

But when I run it, I get this error

> [S0001][8102] Line 2: Cannot update identity column 'Id'.

How I can fix this?

Comment: You can't; the error is telling you the problem. You can't `UPDATE` the value of an `IDENTITY`, which you are attempted to do when you match the row. You can provide a value for it when you `INSERT` the row, with `IDENTITY_INSERT`, but after that it is "set in stone". Though why are you trying to `UPDATE` the row at all? If the value equals the other value, assigning it the value is pointless.

Comment: `ON (t.[Id] = s.[Id])` means the two IDs are already identical. There's no reason to update that column. In fact, it can lead to quite unexpected bugs

Comment: That `UPDATE
SET t.[Id] = s.[Id]` can lead to an unexpected duplicate key error. I had a similar clause in a MERGE statement created by a code generator and kept getting a duplicate error, even though the values are clearly identical. This shouldn't matter. There's no way there could be duplicates. And yet .... MERGE is very quirky. For starters, it's NOT atomic. You need to use an explicit transaction. Second, as I found out, for some reason even in 2019 modifying the JOIN key makes the query engine see the same row twice. You should *REMOVE* that field assignment

Comment: @GoldenLion that's not what your code says. Your code updates the JOIN fields. `UPDATE SET t.[Id] = s.[Id]`

Comment: @AaronBertrand you don't stress `you could end up with race conditions or primary key conflicts` enough. When I first run into just this case I asked another SQL Server MVP who couldn't think what the issue could be.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Probably not, but I tend to lean toward urging people to just ditch MERGE altogether anyway rather than making it suck slightly less.

Comment: UPDATE SET TARGET.[value]=SOURCE.[value] is the values being merge.  You can not have id in the merged list.  id is used for the join criteria. join criteria can not be updated.

Answer (score -3):

Problem: You can not update any join fields in a merge

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Survey].[Portfolio] ON turns off the autonumber.  This command tells sql server not to autonumber during the insert in the merge.

You can not merge with the autonumber on

the identity field is used a join field in this example.

UPDATE SET TARGET.[value]=SOURCE.[value] is the values being merged. You can not have id in the merged list. id is used for the join criteria. join criteria can not be updated.

Merge is used to combine a source table into a target table based on unique join condition.  I manually add values for id and value for the source and target table.  I then merge the data between the source and target table and show the results.

```
--I create a target and source table

if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_target') is not null
    drop table #tmp_target;
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_source') is not null
    drop table #tmp_source;

Create table #tmp_target
(
  id bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
  value int
);

Create table #tmp_source
(
id bigint IDENTITY(1,1), 
value int
);

 set identity_insert #tmp_source ON;
 insert into #tmp_source(id,value) values(1,1),(2,2)
 set identity_insert #tmp_source OFF;

 set identity_insert #tmp_target ON;
 insert into #tmp_target(id,value) values(1,3),(2,4)
 set identity_insert #tmp_target OFF;

 select * from #tmp_source
 select * from #tmp_target


 set identity_insert #tmp_target ON;
 MERGE #tmp_target  as TARGET USING #tmp_source as SOURCE ON    (TARGET.[id]=SOURCE.[id]) 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN  UPDATE SET TARGET.[value]=SOURCE.[value] 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT(id,value)  Values(SOURCE.[id],SOURCE.[value])  
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;


-- merge has three conditions: when matched, when not matched, 
when not matched by source:   Intersection, no Intersection, and compliment

 select * from #tmp_target
```

outputs

```
Source
id value
1 1
2 2

target
id value
1  3
2  4

merge
id value
1   1
2   2
```

Comment: That command *doesn't* say to not autonumber. `IDENTITY_INSERT`controls whether an explicit value can be inserted, not whether autonumbering works. The default is `OFF` which means inserting an explicit value isn't allowed

Comment: @EugeneSukh what's the point of that update anyway? The two values are equal already